# Does the Repair Facility speed the creation of colonists?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

The [Repair Facility](http://m.ign.com/wikis/civ-beyond-earth/Repair_Facility) provides the following bonus:

> +10% Production for Land Units
>   [image: Repair Facility]

But that leaves me wondering does that cover non-military units like the worker or colonist.  The colonist is unique in that it stops food production, so if there is any exception to the production bonus the colonist would be it.

Does the Repair Facility's "+10% Production for Land Units" apply to colonists and all non-combat land units?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the bonus applies to workers and colonists as well as explorers and "traditional" military units.

I loaded up a late-game save and checked with a newly settled city that had relatively low production.  The game speed was quick, so the numbers might not align with your numbers if you play at a different speed.

No Repair Facility:

- Colonist: 15 turns (124 production at 8.8/turn)
- Worker: 6 turns (40 production at 7.8/turn)
- Explorer: 4 turns (26 production at 7.8/turn)
- Aegis: 13 turns (120 production at 9.3/turn)

(I have some bonus military production abilities, which is why I get additional production per turn for the Aegis that you don't see otherwise.  Also note that the Colonist gets bonus production because the city rebalances citizens when you pick it)

I then purchased a Repair Facility in that city.

With Repair Facility:

- Colonist: 14 turns (124 production at 9.4/turn)
- Worker: 5 turns (40 production at 8.4/turn)
- Explorer: 4 turns (26 production at 8.4/turn)
- Aegis: 13 turns (120 production at 9.9/turn)

As you can see, adding the Repair Facility boosted the production rate of both the military units and the non-military units.  It didn't seem to be 10% for me, but it's possible that it's 10% of the base production and other modifiers were already applied in my first set of numbers.  Regardless, there was an improvement in production from the Repair Facility.

Comment: It looks like all of those units gained an extra 0.6 production per turn. Does this mean your base production for the city was at 6 and you have additional bonuses increasing production speeds for those units?

Comment: @Ellesedil, I believe so.  This was a late-game save and I had a lot of wonders and other bonuses in effect, despite the fact that this was a "fresh" city with no buildings.